# Benchmarking Nginx against Express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have Nginx set up as a reverse proxy in front of my express application.

So every request that comes to Nginx is proxied to express running on 4 ports. Both Nginx and express run on the same hosts .

After having read that all the static content should be served by Nginx and Express should be left for dynamic requests only, I gave it a shot and set up the Nginx config . It works perfectly . So now all JS / CSS and HTML assets are served by Nginx itself.

Now how do I prove that this is a better setup in terms of numbers ? Should I use some tool to simulate requests ( to both older and the newer setup ), and compare the average load times of assets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser => Dev tools => Networks

Here you can see the network wait time and download time for every request. So you can open your webpage and compare it with both the configs.
This can be helpful on a local env so latency has minimal effect on testing.

Other than that you can do a load test. Google load testing tools!

Comment: Developer tools would not very convincing I think. After all how many calls will I trigger ? Load test seems a better options - triggering a large no. of calls and then comparing the average load times.

Comment: @MayurArora Both serve a different perspective. Browser will give you performance improvements from a single user's view. Load test will also take into account the resource hogging parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, "benchmark."  You have two configurations.  You need to understand the efficiencies under each model.   To do so you need to instrument the hosts to collect data on the finite resources (CPU, DISK, MEMORY, NETWORK and related sub statistics) as well as response times.

Any performance testing tool which exercises the HTTP interface and allows for the collection and aggregation of your monitoring data while under test should do the trick.   You should be able to collect information on the most common paths through your site, the number of users on your system for any given slice of time, the average session duration (iteration interval) all from an examination of the logs.    The most common traversals then become the basis for the business processes you will need to replicate with your performance testing tool.

If you have no engaged in performance testing efforts before then this would be a good time to tag someone in your organization who does this work on an ongoing basis.  The learning curve is steep and (if you haven't done this before and you have no training or mentor) fairly long.   You can burn a lot of cycles on poor tests/benchmark executions before you get it "right" where you can genuinely compare the performance of configuration A to configuration B.